# How to use if else condition inside a block loop in printing CSV in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am to ROR and I just wonder if how can I print a CSV with some conditions on a specifid data coming from my query? I didn't use some design patterns because I am a newbie. I just want to know if is this is possible in printing CSV in ruby on rails.

Here is the sample code in the given model to print CSV.

```
def self.cross_mri_transfer_to_csv
      attributes = %w{
        employee_name
        location_assignment
        job_grade_position
        from_institution
        from_cluster
        from_region
        from_area
        from_unit
        to_institution
        to_cluster
        to_region
        to_area
        to_unit
        status
        initiated_by
        approved_by
        endorsed_by
        confirmed_by
        start_date
        applied_at
            }
      CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
        csv << attributes.map{|e| e.split("_").map(&:capitalize).join(' ')}
        all.each do |employee_event|
          csv << [ 
            employee_event.employee.fullname_formal,
            employee_event.location_assignment,
            employee_event.job_grade_position,
            employee_event.event_data[:old][:institution_name],
            employee_event.event_data[:old][:cluster_name],
            employee_event.event_data[:old][:region_name],
            employee_event.event_data[:old][:area_name],
            employee_event.event_data[:old][:unit_name],
            employee_event.event_data[:new][:institution_name],
            employee_event.event_data[:new][:cluster_name],
            employee_event.event_data[:new][:region_name],
            employee_event.event_data[:new][:area_name],
            employee_event.event_data[:new][:unit_name],
            employee_event.status,

            if (employee_event.steps.where(step_type: :initiate).first.performed_actor.present?)
              employee_event.steps.where(step_type: :initiate).first.performed_actor.fullname_formal.upcase,
            else
              none,
            end

            if (employee_event.steps.where(step_type: :approve).first.performed_actor.present?)
              employee_event.steps.where(step_type: :approve).first.performed_actor.fullname_formal.upcase,
            else
              none,
            end

            if (employee_event.steps.where(step_type: :endorse).first.performed_actor.present?)
              employee_event.steps.where(step_type: :endorse).first.performed_actor.fullname_formal.upcase,
            else
              none,
            end

            if (employee_event.steps.where(step_type: :confirm).first.performed_actor.present?)
              employee_event.steps.where(step_type: :confirm).first.performed_actor.fullname_formal.upcase,
            else
              none,
            end

            employee_event.start_date,
            employee_event.applied_at 
            ]
        end
      end
    end
```

I know there is something wrong in the code with syntax error. It is just a presentation or example. But is this possible in printing CSV? Sorry for the question but I just want to know because I tried goggling this for a day but didn't find out anything there :(

Appreciate if someone can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move your `if else end` statements to the variables, and put variables on their places instead.

Comment: or move them to private methods and call the methods in there place. Also, What is none? Is it a variable?.

Comment: @xeon131 My guess is that this method is defined within a Rails model, so that's: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/none

Comment: [refactoring suggestions] Please move this to a separate class and call that class to generate the csv instead of dumping this code in a model

Comment: Gottta find a way to refactor this code its too messy. Sorry I am new to ROR and I really want to improve and learn some design pattern techniques. Thanks for the tip guy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the array definition. For example:

```
[
  # ...
  employee_event.status,

  if (...)
    employee_event.steps.where(step_type: :initiate).etc.etc,
  else
    none,
  end

  # ...
]
```

Should instead be written as:

```
[
  # ...
  employee_event.status,

  if (...)
    employee_event.steps.where(step_type: :initiate).etc.etc
  else
    none
  end, # <--- !!!!!

  # ...
]
```

You can think this code as saying "the array element is the return value of the `if` statement".

Each item in the array must be separated by a comma, and you are only adding one item to the array for each `if` statement.

There are, as others have suggested, many other ways that the code could be improved; but this should resolve your immediate problem.

Comment: Thankyou so much! Is there someway where can I put the code instead of the model. Cause I am really new to ROR and I want to find a way to clean this code in the model.